# I'm getting a very general error on my Haskell code: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

Tags: haskell

I have the following code, that takes inputs 'a' the integral coefficients and 'b' the integral powers in some polynomial expression in x, along with integers 'l' and 'r'. It uses rectangles of thickness 0.001 to estimate the integral between x=l and x=r. It then calculates the volume traced by the curve on rotation about the x-axis, by adding up volumes of the the cylinders traced by the rectangles of thickness 0.001.

I have made sure the indentations are fine, and have checked the code several times for correctness. The error is so general that I have no ideas on where I should start troubleshooting.

```hs
solve :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Double]
solve l r a b = let list1 = [l, (l+0.001)..(r-0.001)] 
                           arealist = [(expression x a b)*0.001 |  x<-list1]
                           volumelist = [(0.001*pi*(expression x a b)^2 |  x<- list1]
                       in [sum(arealist), sum(volumelist)]
```

The function 'expression' is defined as follows

```hs
expression :: Integer ->  [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Double
expression x [] [] = 0.0
expression x a b = fromIntegral(head(a))*fromIntegral(x^(head(b)) + (expression x (tail(a)) (tail(b)))
```

The expected output is a list of 2 elements, the integral along with the volume of the cylinder. I have the following error

```hs
 parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
11 | solve :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Double]
   | ^
```

Comment: Do you actually have `solve l r a b = . . .` indented like that?

Comment: The function body should be lined up with the type signature, on the left - yours is indented.

Comment: You should not indent the function definition. It has the same level as the signature.

Comment: I tried to line up the definition with the signature. It still produces the same error

Comment: All the equations in the `let` should also be indented at the same level.

Comment: Sorry about that, I think there was a mess up while pasting my code. The let expressions are indeed correctly indented in my original code, and so is the in expression

Comment: `solve :: solve ::` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Don't edit your code to resolve errors pointed out in an answer.

Comment: I find studying other people's Haskell code to be a useful way of assimilating the language, even if I don't understand entirely what it is I'm reading.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell is sensitive to whitespace and indentation. In this particular case, it's about indentation of the function definition: it needs to be indented at the same level as the type signature:

```
solve :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Double]
solve l r a b = ...
```

And same goes for your definition of `expression`.

After you fix this issue, the next one is that your `let` bindings are not aligned.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I corrected this and I still get the same error.

Comment: Well, your `let` bindings are also not aligned, as well as `in`

Comment: But you can't actually be getting _the exact same_ error. The error quoted in your original question does point at `solve`. The error you're getting now must be pointing somewhere else. So take a look there.

Comment: It is indeed the exact same error, pointing at the line 11 as in the question

Comment: It's almost certainly because the bad type signature `f :: f :: ...`

Comment: @ThomasMDuBuisson that bad signature wasn't there in the original question. It must have been added later. Perhaps another typo.

Comment: if the error being pointed at is really the initial `s` of `solve` in the type signature, then the *real* error is almost certainly on the line(s) before it. If that is line 11, we need to know what's in lines 1-10.

Comment: I've rolled the question back to the original code.

Comment: @RobinZigmond The lines 1-10 are just the function 'expression' as in the question, and one `import Text.Printf (printf)` in the beginning, that's all

Comment: That's 4 lines, not 10. And you didn't specify the indentation of the import